# MYSQL php date filter

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a question about doing this filter in mysql.
I have a date with 3 dates.

```
1-start date; Ex: 10-04-2017
2-end date; Ex: 04-20-2017
3-date completion; Ex 23-04-2017
```

If the order is delivered between the start date and the end date it is on time and will record the completion date;
But if the order is delivered after it will record a date higher than the correct end date?
So I wanted to filter and list those orders that were delivered late.
What should I do?

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` with a comparison on the columns.

Comment: The end date is before the start date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have an orders table with 3 different dates as you mentioned in your post. Assume that your orders table have four columns (id, startDate, endDate, compDate) to keep it simple. Now SQL of your MySQL Database is given as:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `startDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `endDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `compDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Assume there are three records in your orders table, two of which are late orders that is they exceed the endDate :

```
/*Data for the table `orders` */
insert  into `orders`(`id`,`startDate`,`endDate`,`compDate`) values
(1,'2017-04-10 00:00:00','2017-04-20 00:00:00','2017-04-23 00:00:00'),
(2,'2017-04-10 00:00:00','2017-04-20 00:00:00','2017-04-19 00:00:00'),
(3,'2017-04-10 00:00:00','2017-04-20 00:00:00','2017-04-22 00:00:00');
```

Now you need to run the following simple SQL statement with filter (compDate > endDate) to check for those orders that were delivered late:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE compDate > endDate;
```

it will give you two late delivered records with id 1 and 3. (i.e., late orders.)

[Click here to see the Sqlyog query snapshot that displays late orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcqT2.png)

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: One last doubt, and how do I filter only what is this current month? I tried like this:SELECT * FROM obra WHERE compDate like '%04-2017' > endDate

Comment: Try this:    
 `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( 2017, '-', 04 ),'%Y-%m' ) < endDate ;`

Hope this will solve your problem.